# Select query using inner join in plsql for loop fails

Tags: oracle, plsql, cascade

**This is my plsql block**

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN ( SELECT T.table_name FROM user_tables T INNER JOIN (SELECT distinct to_char(SYSTEM_DATE,'yyyymmdd') as sys_date FROM *) ON T.table_name LIKE '%' || sys_date || '%' )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || c.table_name || ' CASCADE';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Am getting missing keyword error

```
Error report:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at line 4
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can you please tell what's wrong in the code?

Comment: Is it Oracle or PostgreSQL or other DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [Standard DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9003.htm#SQLRF01806)

You will understand that you need to write the `DROP` statement as -

```
DROP TABLE TABLE_NAME CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

Your SQL is missing the `CONSTRAINTS` keyword

Comment: @sigapriyakannan - you can mark the question as answered, if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

`DROP TABLE ' || c.table_name || ' CASCADE` is a working statement in **[PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-droptable.html)**

> DROP TABLE name [, ...] [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]

But not in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9003.htm) which expect no CASCADE or `CASCADE CONSTRAINTS` clause:

> Specify CASCADE CONSTRAINTS to drop all referential integrity constraints that refer to primary and unique keys in the dropped table. If you omit this clause, and such referential integrity constraints exist, then the database returns an error and does not drop the table.